# parse XML from php

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml file (see below) that I want to parse with php to output Filename and RomUrl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ota.xsd">
    <Stable>
        <cheeseburger>
            <Filename>crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180128-cheeseburger-v4.0-BETA5</Filename>
            <RomUrl
                id="rom"
                title="Downloads"
                description="Download latest builds">dl url here for cheeseburger</RomUrl>
        </cheeseburger>

        <dumpling>
            <Filename>crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180127-dumpling-v4.0-BETA</Filename>
            <RomUrl
                id="rom"
                title="Downloads"
                description="Download latest build">dl url here for dumpling</RomUrl>
        </dumpling>
     </Stable>
</OTA>
```

I would like to be able to output like so:

```
cheeseburger
crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180128-cheeseburger-v4.0-BETA5
dl url here for cheeseburger

dumpling
crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180127-dumpling-v4.0-BETA
dl url here for dumpling
```

Now I am stuck at looping through each element 
Here is my code I have so far

```
<?php
// Devices.xml reader 

// check if file exists and read it
if (file_exists('devices.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('devices.xml');

    //echo $xml->Stable->dumpling->Filename;
    echo "<br>";
    foreach($xml->Stable as $device) {
        echo '<h2>' . $device->Filename . '</h2>';
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    //var_dump($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open devices.xml.');
}
?>
```

Now I am sure there might be better options, yet I am not that familiar with XML in php, so any help is highly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$device` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) which you can loop using a `foreach`.

Then you can access the `$key` to get for example "cheeseburger", and `$item` (which is also of type SimpleXMLElement) to get the properties like "Filename". .

```
if (file_exists('devices.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('devices.xml');
    foreach($xml->Stable as $device) {
        foreach ($device as $key => $item) {
            echo $key . "<br>";
            echo $item->Filename . "<br>";
            echo $item->RomUrl . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    exit('Failed to open devices.xml.');
}
```

That will result in:

```
cheeseburger
crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180128-cheeseburger-v4.0-BETA5
dl url here for cheeseburger

dumpling
crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180127-dumpling-v4.0-BETA
dl url here for dumpling
```